# ReactJS: this.state is undefined on lifecycle hook

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a simple electron-react component.
This component queries enabled Network Interfaces, pushes the data to the state and renders it to the DOM. The component doesn't work because of this error:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined" at this line:
    "data = this.state.data.slice();"
Why is this.state undefined? did I miss binding something? Thanks for any advice.

```
import React from "react";
import os from "os";

export default class GetInterfaces extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: []
        };
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        let ifaces = os.networkInterfaces();
        Object.keys(ifaces).forEach(function (ifname) {
            let data;
            ifaces[ifname].forEach(function (iface) {
                if (iface.internal === true || iface.family === "IPv6") {
                    return;
                }
                let networkInterface = {
                    name: ifname,
                    mac: iface.mac,
                    ip: iface.address
                };
                data = this.state.data.slice();
                data.push(networkInterface);
                this.setState({ data: data });
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        const networkInterfaces = this.state.data.map((networkInterface, index) =>
            <ListGroupItem key={index}>
                <i class="fa fa-wifi"></i>
                <span>{networkInterface.name}</span>
                <input type="checkbox"></input>
            </ListGroupItem>
        );

        return (
            <div>
                {networkInterfaces}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: And sorry for poor text formatting!

Comment: binding problem in forEach function, see the duplicate and you will know how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think "this" is becoming unbound in the .forEach function, so you can try the trick of saving the context before it like this

```js
componentDidMount() {
    let ifaces = os.networkInterfaces();
    let that = this;  // Note the saving of the context
    
    Object.keys(ifaces).forEach(function (ifname) {
        let data;
        ifaces[ifname].forEach(function (iface) {
            if (iface.internal === true || iface.family === "IPv6") {
                return;
            }
            let networkInterface = {
                name: ifname,
                mac: iface.mac,
                ip: iface.address
            };
            data = this.state.data.slice();
            data.push(networkInterface);
            that.setState({ data: data });  // And then using the saved context
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Wow this was not mentioned anywhere! which functions overrides this?

Answer (score 0):

this happens because you are losing your `this` context inside `forEach` call

as [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/forEach) says you can pass additional parameter to `forEach`, which is `thisArg`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    let ifaces = os.networkInterfaces();
    Object.keys(ifaces).forEach(function (ifname) {
        ...
    }, this);
}
```